# Do we tag based on the question content, or the expected audience for a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was having a discussion with a user about whether certain tags were appropriate to a question, when it got me thinking about the reason behind why a tag is used.

Does a tag identify the subject and content of the question itself? If we ask a question about a C++ application, naturally we use the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

But what about the expected audience for the *answers*? For example, the audience for a 3D graphics question might be all OpenGL users. But those answers could equally apply to D3D users. Or users of neither API, with some kind of software rasterizer. Or whatever.

Is it appropriate to add tags based on the people who might find the question useful, even if the tag itself is not directly appropriate to the content of the question?

This question is a bit similar to this [question on the "poisoning" of certain tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70538/poisoning-of-api-related-tags-on-stack-overflow), except it's more investigative (I don't have a belief either way; I want to know what the prevailing wind is). Are we supposed to tag based on the expected audience for a question, or *solely* for the question's content?

Comment: In the case of graphics APIs I'd say it depends on whether or not the question is API agnostic (though to what extent that's possible I don't directly see). But in general I'd say to only tag a question with tags appropriate for the question, not for the intended audience.

Comment: @Bart: I agree with Bart, with this enhancement; tags should directly describe the contents of the question, and the title should be descriptive enough to attract the wider community who might have interest in the question.

Answer (score 5):

The tags should describe the content, adding tags just because those users might also be interested is not a good idea. This would reduce the usefulness of the tag system and encourage users to add useless tags to gain more exposure for their posts.

But I would also not be too strict about this, and I would generally try to have at least one very general tag for a question, even if more specific tags would be a sufficient categorization of the question. Too specific tagging can hide the question from users that could answer it, but don't follow those specific tags.

If there is a mismatch between the tags that actually describe the question, and the tags the target audience for that question are following, then it might be necessary to adjust the tagging schema.